# PHP file_get_contents Returns 504 on Larger Files

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm building a PHP website that downloads JSON files from MySociety's EveryPolitician. Some of these files are small while others are super massive. Here are two examples of the typical request that I'm making:

```
$g = file_get_contents("https://cdn.rawgit.com/everypolitician/everypolitician-data/65c4534/data/US_Virgin_Islands/Legislature/ep-popolo-v1.0.json");
```

And

```
$g = file_get_contents("https://cdn.rawgit.com/everypolitician/everypolitician-data/65c4534/data/UK/Commons/ep-popolo-v1.0.json");
```

The first line works fine which I believe is because of the small scale of the file being requested, but the second line loads forever in the browser, before returning a Gateway Timeout error (504).

If I point my browser to the second URL, it loads fine (though after a few seconds; after all, it is quite big). For now, the script is running on my local machine, so there isn't a difference in bandwidth or internet speed. As you can see, both files are from GitHub.

Confusing me more is that the second line did actually work once, a couple of days ago.

Is this just a limitation of PHP's file_get_contents()? Is there any way to get around it using file_get_contents() or is there another library that would work better in this case?

Comment: curl is more robust and configurable than file_get_contents

Comment: and [Guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) is a more user-friendly wrapper around curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting the default socket timeout as such:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 360);
```

Which would give the file_get_contents() 6 minutes to attempt its connection.  Additionally, you could create a context array and pass it along to the file_get_contents() function which would make it so you didn't have to change the ini value ala:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array( 
    'http' => array( 
        'timeout' => 360 
        ) 
    ) 
);
file_get_contents("https://cdn.rawgit.com/everypolitician/everypolitician-data/65c4534/data/UK/Commons/ep-popolo-v1.0.json", 0, $context);
```

Hope this helps